# adding module in nodejs app raises error

Tags: node.js, module, console

I need to integrate a specific part of code to the nodejs app

that part uses

```
 var request = require('request');
```

but when this particular function is called on fly then there's an error in console that

```
require is not defined.
```

How can this be settled?

Comment: how are you running your script?

Comment: using the terminal node app_name

and then through localhost in browser

Comment: when you run `node script_name` in terminal you get this error? What version of Node are you using? What OS?

Comment: no when I use this particular script through terminal then it works fine.

but in the website when this script is called by another function, then this exception is raised in the console

Please tell me how modules are installed in nodejs apps

..i dont see any other require being used

Comment: You can't use `require` in the browser. On the server Node handles `require`, in the browser either use a `<script>` tag or something like browserify. But generally speaking, you won't use `request` on the client side.

Comment: how to use a script tag?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you are using the same languaje for server side and client side scripting you don't have the same tools on both sides. [require](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require) is a function provided by the Nodejs runtime environment to all modules once evaluated. It is not available by default on the Web browser environment and therefore you can't use it there. There are solutions to this but may be they can't be applied to your case. The [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) package you refer in your question is meant to be used on the server side, not on the client side. You need to consider replacing that code with something that fit better your use case.

Answer (score -1):

look this ... is a perfect example for start a Node JS application!

http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html

using Express.js